# How to run commands on another cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to run commands on 2 cmds while opening the same file, like if I open a .bat file It opens 2 cmd and they run 2 differents commands (1 each). It's possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right this is what you want to do, note it's a batch file:

```cmd
@echo off
start cmd /c "echo 1st command && pause"
start cmd /c "echo 2nd command && pause"
```

Read about [`cmd` here](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb490880.aspx) and about [`start` here](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb491005.aspx). The following switches of the `cmd` command can be considered:

> **/c:** Carries out the command specified by string and then stops.
>   **/k:** Carries out the command specified by string and continues.

Instead of using `/k` I used `/c` with a `pause` command to show the concatenation of 2 commands here.

To concate 2 commands use `commandA && commandB` which is described here at [ss64](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) which is a great site when it comes to batch scripting:

> `commandA && commandB`: Run `commandA`, if it succeeds then run `commandB`

---

As requested another example with `cd`, `dir` and `pause` could look like:

```cmd
@echo off
start cmd /c "cd C:\Users\ && dir && pause"
start cmd /c "cd C:\ && dir && pause"
```

It changes the directory, prints the directory list and wait for use input.

Comment: can you make me an example with 2 commands like "cd" or something else please? EDIT I made this to "practice" and the cmd says "press a key to continue" and it closes
'code'
@echo off
start cmd /c "echo cd Desktop && pause"
start cmd /c "echo cd C:\ && pause"
'code'

Comment: @PlayLikeMe10YT: My example consists of 2 commands `echo` and `pause`. What exactly do you need?

Comment: I edited the comment before sorry for formatting I'm a newbie and I don't exactly know how it works
'code'
@echo off
start cmd /c "echo cd Desktop && pause"
start cmd /c "echo cd C:\ && pause"

Comment: @PlayLikeMe10YT: Extended my answer. If you use `cd` you don't want to `echo` that but want to execute the actual command...